# Is there a way of determining if tor is running on a remote machine?

Tags: network, network-scanners, tor, ports, detection

In most of the companies, IT guys block some sites and by using TOR or other VPNs people walk around these blocks and gain access to blocked content.

My question is, assuming TOR is running on default set up (downloaded Tor Browser and hit run) is there a way to catch this? Could there be a default port that can be cought by nmap?

I tried to google -and will keep on googleing-... anybody with an idea?

-if i find a way, I will also post it-

Comment: I don't think Tor opens any public listening sockets, so you would have to analyse traffic as a MITM. From that point it's probably easy to fingerprint it, guessing there's a Layer7 rule for it.

Comment: well, i am quite unsure how would you classify packets?

plus even if you could, seems like a lot of hard work?

Finally, it could be any encrypted data?

Comment: You would use deep-packet inspection on a firewall/router/gateway and l7 filtering http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/protocols It isn't hard work if you're the netadmin but you're right, it won't be perfect, users can circumvent it, and you'll go on and on in a loop of getting more and more draconian until users resort to bringing in their own Internet connections. You need to make this feedback loop communicative and not tit-for-tat, so you're working together and not against one another.

Comment: put i am not an IT admin, can not change firewall rules...
i am a pentester trying to pin-point naughty workers

Answer (score 4):

Tor in its default installation only opens the `SocksPost` locally. There are no ports which are listening at some network interface. So from looking at a remote machine you can't find out if a person uses Tor or not.

However when you're looking at the machine's network traffic you are able to see more. If the user has Tor running there is a connection to some relay. It is easy to find out all addresses of running relays and look if the user connects to one of those.

I think it is the wrong approach to consider them [naughty](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51925/is-there-a-way-of-determining-if-tor-is-running-on-a-remote-machine#comment81868_51925). There are [many reasons](https://www.torproject.org/about/torusers.html.en) why using Tor is a good idea.

Comment: by naughty i did not mean porn or anything... more like as in 'he is making a list, checking it twice, he knows who is naughty and nice' :) i meant as people who doesn't obey firewall rules...

can I tell the difference between some other encrypted data transfer protocol and tor? Maybe user has a remote secure netcat running with someone in Sweeden for some valid reason?

Where does the data come to the user than? port 80?